# Use Mouse Wheel to control system volume

Tags: windows, macros, mouse, volume

Is there any way to set up a macro of some sort so that I can use my mouse wheel (or perhaps fn + mousewheel) to control the system volume on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) proved to be an incredibly intuitive way to accomplish this. Personally, I mapped it to Windows key and scroll wheel, using

```
#WheelDown::Volume_Down
#WheelUp::Volume_Up
```

Comment: Since you went to the trouble to find the program and apply it to your specific need, perhaps you could at least briefly describe the steps you used to address that need (i.e. where in the program the configuration is for that particular feature, and how you set it up).

Comment: Sure!
The help pages on Autohotkey are really helpful, especially the [commands page](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands.htm). For me, I just used 

`#WheelDown::Volume_Down
#WheelUp::Volume_Up`